# Breeze - Comparison of DenseVector gives me a BitVector - is this intentional?

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

```
    import breeze.linalg._

    val dm = DenseMatrix(0.0, 5.0, 6.0)

    dm :== 6.0

    val dv = DenseVector(0.0, 5.0, 6.0)

    dv :== 6.0
```

gives me

```
dm: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double] =
0.0
5.0
6.0

res0: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Boolean] =
false
false
true

dv: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(0.0, 5.0, 6.0)

res1: breeze.linalg.BitVector = BitVector(2)
```

I was expecting a DenseVector[Boolean] 
false
false
true

Is this an intentional construct - can someone explain it for me? I found it confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `DenseVector` by `(dv :== 6.0).toDeseVector`.

I'm not sure about reasons of this asymmetry, I guess authors probably were more concerned about performance in case of `DenseVector`. See [DenseVector source](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/master/math/src/main/scala/breeze/linalg/operators/DenseVectorOps.scala#L109) vs [DenseMatrix source](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze/blob/master/math/src/main/scala/breeze/linalg/operators/DenseMatrixOps.scala#L1350).